# Symmetry breaks on mesh after applying solidify

Tags: mirror, mirror-modifier, solidify-modifier

I am attempting to apply a solidify modifier on a mesh. The goal is to use this solidify to create stylized outlines on the mesh. I am using a vertex group to control the strenght of the solidify.

On the selected areas in the image, the weight of solidify is set to 0.
On rest of the mesh it is set to 1. After applying the solidify modifier the symmetry on the mesh breaks as such:
[image: Moving vertex with X axis mesh symmetry]

At first I thought the mesh must not be perfectly symmetrical, however after mirroring it again this behaviour still persists. Any ideas on what is causing this?